# How can I hide My account entry title only on the login page?

Tags: woocommerce

I have woocommerce online shop, where I separated login and registration pages. I have only one problem left, and that is the entry-title. I would like to remove it from the login page/form, but leave it in My account page/endpoints (Dashboard, Orders, Addresses and etc.).

Link structure:

Login: mysite.com/my-account/

Sign up: mysite.com/registration/

Unfortunately css like this:

`.page-id-111 h1.entry-title { display: none; }`

Doesn't solve the problem

Is it possible to do this?

Thank you!

Comment: Please check below mention answer and let me know if it's working for you or not.

Answer (score 0):

Please try below CSS, it will help you to hide it from the Login page:

```
body:not(.logged-in).woocommerce-account h1.entry-title {
    display: none;
}
```

Please let me know if you find any issues.